# Syntax Error when Using Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using `CASE` statement to print various seasons based on select statement value

```
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN (SELECT po.startdate 
                FROM TABLE1 po
                JOIN TABLE2 a ON po.paramid = a.paramid
                WHERE po.paramid = 60)
             THEN 
                (CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, po.STARTDATE) < 3 
                         THEN 'Winter'
                      WHEN DATEPART(month, po.STARTDATE) = 3 
                         THEN 
                            CASE WHEN DATEPART(day, po.STARTDATE) < 01 
                                    THEN 'Winter' 
                                    ELSE 'Spring' 
                            END
                     WHEN DATEPART(month, po.STARTDATE) < 6 
                        THEN 'Spring'
                     WHEN DATEPART(month, po.STARTDATE) = 6 
                        THEN
                           CASE WHEN DATEPART(day, po.STARTDATE) < 21 
                                   THEN 'Spring' 
                                   ELSE 'Summer' 
                           END
                    WHEN DATEPART(month, po.STARTDATE) < 9 
                       THEN 'Summer'
                    WHEN DATEPART(month, po.STARTDATE) = 9 
                       THEN 
                          CASE WHEN DATEPART(day, po.STARTDATE) < 21 
                                  THEN 'Summer' 
                                  ELSE 'Autumn' 
                          END
                   WHEN DATEPART(month, po.STARTDATE) < 12 
                      THEN 'Autumn'
                   WHEN DATEPART(month, po.STARTDATE) = 12 
                      THEN
                         CASE WHEN DATEPART(day, po.STARTDATE) < 1 
                                 THEN 'Autumn' 
                                 ELSE 'Winter' 
                         END) 
    END) 
FROM 
    tABLE1 PO
```

Error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN'.

Please can someone suggest what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Is this for Oracle? If so, what version?

Comment: incorrect tag sorry. SQL

Comment: *What* SQL? Every dialect is different. What syntax error are you getting? Can you edit to include the *exact* text?

Comment: its ms-sql, I dont have permission to chose that tag from the list apparently

Comment: The tag used here is `sql-server`, sometimes there's others that are just aliases, which might be the problem you were having.

Comment: ok I have included the exact error

Comment: Can anyone actually read this query and figure out what it should be doing?  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot imagine that a query of this form actually does anything useful.  However, your specific problem is right at the beginning:

```
SELECT (case when (select po.startdate
                   from TABLE1 po join
                        TABLE2 a
                        on po.paramid = a.paramid
                   where po.paramid = 60
                  )
             then . . .
```

The `case` is expecting a boolean condition.  It is getting a date.  Hence, an error.  An easy way to fix this error is:

```
SELECT (case when exists (select po.startdate
                          from TABLE1 po join
                               TABLE2 a
                               on po.paramid = a.paramid
                          where po.paramid = 60
                         )
             then . . .
```

I don't know if that is the intended logic.  And, I'm almost certain that if the query ran it would not do what you want (the alias `po` is suspiciously defined twice).

I would advise you to ask another question.  Describe the logic you want to implement.  Provide sample data and desired results.  I suspect that a subquery is not needed at all for what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.My issue is resolved please ignore the initial join that is only  for example.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your error has to do with the syntax and formatting used which looks to be malformed. Rather than correct the error, I'd tackle the issue fresh from scratch.

With that in mind, what you look to be trying to do is return the season based on specific date ranges. Others may have an alternate way but one approach is like so;

```
SELECT (CASE 
        WHEN d.DateMonth < 3 OR d.DateMonth = 12
            THEN 'Winter'
        WHEN d.DateMonth >=3 AND (d.DateMonth < 6
                                      OR (d.DateMonth = 6 AND d.DateDay < 21))
            THEN 'Spring'
        WHEN (d.DateMonth = 6 AND d.DateDay >= 21)
             AND (d.DateMonth < 9
                    OR (d.DateMonth = 9 AND d.DateDay < 21))
            THEN 'Summer'
        ELSE 'Autumn'
    END) AS Season
FROM TABLE1 po
JOIN TABLE2 a
  ON po.paramid=a.paramid
-- select the date components we want rather than calling
-- DATEPART each time we need a date segment
OUTER APPLY (SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, po.StartDate) AS DateMonth,
                    DATEPART(DAY, po.StartDate) AS DateDay) d
WHERE po.paramid=60
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but i need join inside the case statement.. resolved the issue by Gordon's  suggestion..